# Acceder a datos de un JSON y convertirlos en un array

Tags: javascript, json, api

Estoy obteniendo estos valores de un json,

```
"files": [
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Voluptatibus quod ab.",
      "url_files": "https://lorempixel.com/2000/400/?78256",
      "type": "mp4",
      "created_at": "2019-09-24 02:48:56",
      "updated_at": "2019-09-24 02:48:56",
      "pivot": {
        "fileable_id": 288,
        "file_id": 3,
        "fileable_type": "App\\Post",
        "created_at": "2019-09-24 02:50:14",
        "updated_at": "2019-09-24 02:50:14"
      }
]
```

necesito acceder a "`url_files`" y convertirlo en un array.
como puedo hacer con javascript?

Comment: Podrías dar un poco más de contexto? Aparentemente estás trabajando con Laravel. De dónde sale ese JSON y exactamente que querés hacer? Por otro lado falta cerrar una `}` antes del `]`.

Comment: eso lo estoy trayendo desde un API hecha en laravel y son imagenes para una galeria de imagenes, pero para la galería solo necesito la url del archivo en un array por es lo que recibe el componente de galería que estoy usando (https://element.eleme.io/?ref=madewithvuejs.com#/es/component/image#vista-previa-de-la-imagen)

Answer (score 0):

La pregunta dice javascript, por lo cual la respuesta la hare en javascript:

Tienes 2 errores en tu json, el primero es que te falto cerrar una llave, el segundo es que no estas escapando los caracteres \, esto daria errores a la hora de convertir a json y luego de json a array, JSON corregido:

```
"files":[
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Voluptatibus quod ab.",
      "url_files": "https://lorempixel.com/2000/400/?78256",
      "type": "mp4",
      "created_at": "2019-09-24 02:48:56",
      "updated_at": "2019-09-24 02:48:56",
      "pivot": {
        "fileable_id": 288,
        "file_id": 3,
        "fileable_type": "App\/\/Post",
        "created_at": "2019-09-24 02:50:14",
        "updated_at": "2019-09-24 02:50:14"
      }

    }
]
```

Ahora, directamente asi tal cual como esta este json no se puede parsear a un objeto en javascript, yo imagino que el objeto que pusiste no lo pusiste completo, si no que hace parte de otro objeto por ende la propiedad "files", no es parseable en si, esta tendria que estar entre corchetes.

Por ende, si la respuesta que estas recibiendo, no es exactamente igual a la que pusiste, si no que comienza con: [] o {}, perfecto, creo que no habria problema, sin embargo si te arroja ese resultado tal cual como lo pusiste en la pregunta, tendras ya sea que deshacerte de la propiedad files:

```
[
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Voluptatibus quod ab.",
      "url_files": "https://lorempixel.com/2000/400/?78256",
      "type": "mp4",
      "created_at": "2019-09-24 02:48:56",
      "updated_at": "2019-09-24 02:48:56",
      "pivot": {
        "fileable_id": 288,
        "file_id": 3,
        "fileable_type": "App\/\/Post",
        "created_at": "2019-09-24 02:50:14",
        "updated_at": "2019-09-24 02:50:14"
      }

    }
]
```

O bien, poner todo el json dentro de otros corchetes:

```
{
    "files":[
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Voluptatibus quod ab.",
            "url_files": "https://lorempixel.com/2000/400/?78256",
            "type": "mp4",
            "created_at": "2019-09-24 02:48:56",
            "updated_at": "2019-09-24 02:48:56",
            "pivot": {
                "fileable_id": 288,
                "file_id": 3,
                "fileable_type": "App\/\/Post",
                "created_at": "2019-09-24 02:50:14",
                "updated_at": "2019-09-24 02:50:14"
            }

        }
    ]

}
```

Ahora bien, simplemente almacenas esta respuesta de este json en una variable y la parseas con JSON.parse:

```
const objetoJSON = JSON.parse(respuestaTratada);
```

Y ahora simplemente si necesitas acceder a la propiedad url_files y convertirla en array simplemente haz lo siguiente:

```
url_files_array = [objetoJSON.url_files];
```

Comment: Aunque igual me parece muy muy extraño que la respuesta que te da desde laravel no te venga ya convertida a un objeto javascript, no se mucho de laravel, por lo que no puedo opinar mucho acerca de esto, pero igual deberias mirar bien si de verdad lo que estas obteniendo es un string y no un objeto javascript ya parseado como tal...